# How to generate AM and PM log filename using log4j2.13 version

Tags: log4j2

Helllo everyone,

we have log4j from 1.2.8 to log4j2.11, and observed half daily logs files are not generating as expected.Only i can see only AM log files are generating.

```
<RollingFile name="file" fileName="testAMPM.log" filePattern="testAMPM.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-a}" >
      
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %5p %-120m [%t - %c:%L] %n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will not mark this as duplicate because this, [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047286/configure-rollingflie-appender-to-rollover-at-midnight-and-midday-of-each-day) here did not get answered. The answer to another duplicate question does have an example though, so please try [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172879/how-to-generate-half-daily-logs-using-log4j2) first:

```
<RollingFile name="fileAppender" filename ="${logName} append="true" FilePattern="${logName}.$$d{yyyy-MM-dd-a}">
    <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0,12 * * ?" />
</RollingFile>
```

A comment in the first linked duplicate also suggests to check out [Cron Triggering Policy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#TriggeringPolicies), which could provide a better solution to your requirement than a TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
[image]

Just try it out.